# Intel Fortran relocation error, libiomp5.so

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

There is a Fortran code which I am trying to compile which works only with Intel Fortran, and with a recent version, due to some Fortran 2008 features.

I am doing all this on a cluster, by using SSH.

I used to load the module

```
module load compilers/intel/15.1/
```

to use `ifort`. However, the 15.1 version is not sufficient for the compilation of this program. Therefore I loaded the only one more recent available on the cluster,

```
module load compilers/intel/17.0.3/
```

The program compiles.

However, at runtime I get the following error:

```
./myprogram: relocation error: ./myprogram: symbol kmp_aligned_malloc, version VERSION not defined in file libiomp5.so with link time reference
./myprogram: relocation error: ./myprogram: symbol kmp_aligned_malloc, version VERSION not defined in file libiomp5.so with link time reference
./myprogram: relocation error: ./myprogram: symbol kmp_aligned_malloc, version VERSION not defined in file libiomp5.so with link time reference
./myprogram: relocation error: ./myprogram: symbol kmp_aligned_malloc, version VERSION not defined in file libiomp5.so with link time reference
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 22573 on
node splinter-login.local exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There seems to be clash between libraries. am I right? I printed

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH


:/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64/:/lib:/lib64:/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/compiler/lib/intel64:/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/compiler/lib/intel64/:/share/apps/intel/l_ics_2015.1.133/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64
```

so it seems to me that in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` there are still the Intel 15 libraries. Should I subsitute them with the 17 ones? Problem is that in `/share/apps/intel/` there are no 17 libraries...

UPDATE: I did

```
module purge
module load compilers/intel/17.0.3/
recompiled and rerun
```

and sourced the `.sh` file mentioned in the comments
and I still get the same error

Comment: Yes, it looks there you have 2015 items in your environment.  You can see what your module is doing with `module show compilers/intel/17.0.3` (depending on your module system), but you also have the opportunity of using Intel's own setup script (name varies) specific to a particular installation.

Comment: That said, this could be a problem for your local system support team rather than the Internet.

Comment: A "module purge" and reload of the 2017 might help, depends on whatever else you need to load. The output of module list just after the compile fails could be useful as well.

Comment: @IanBush module purge just after execution of the program tells me that the v17 is loaded. And the compilation goes well, the problem comes out at runtime.

Comment: I meant module purge, module load compilers/intel/17.0.3 and then recompile from scratch and re-run. What does module list show just before recompile? But really as said above this is one for your local support team

Comment: This problem should be forwarded to the local support team, as @francescalus mentions. In the meantime, you may try the following fix.  Locate the ifort 2017 by loading it and execute `which ifort`. The command `env | grep 2015\.1\.133` will provide you with all environement variables that are set by the intel compiler environment. Suppress all the entries with the intel path (not the full variables, just the intel part). Then, in the directory found above with `which ifort`, locate and execute a file named `ifortvars.sh` as `source /path/to/ifortvars.sh`

Comment: Or, as @IanBush mentions, you just need to erase all of your object files and start the compilation from scratch. Hopefully, the combination of both tips will solve your problem :-)

Comment: @IanBush thanks for your comments, I followed your advice and I still have the same problem, see update in the question

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I combined yours and Ian's advice, but I still get the same error

Comment: what does `which ifort` return?

Comment: `share/modules/feb_2018/install_dir/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/bin/intel64/ifort`